# Postgres PL/pgSQL To Consolidate Columns Existing Across Various Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am implementing a tool to clean up all customer names across various tables in a schema called `stage`. The customer names could be coming from columns `billing_acc_name` or `cust_acc_names`. I do not know in advance how many tables have these columns, but as long as they do, they will be part of clean up.

However, prior to clean up, I need to select all unique customer names across the tables in the schema.

For better separation of concerns, I am looking at implementing this in PL/pgSQL. Currently, this is how I'm implementing this in Python/pandas/SQLAlchemy etc.

```
table_name = 'information_schema.columns'
table_schema_src = 'stage'
cols = ['billing_acc_name', 'cust_acc_name']

# get list of all table names and column names to query in stage schema
sql = text(f""" 
    SELECT table_name, column_name FROM {table_name} WHERE table_schema ='{table_schema_src}'
    AND column_name = ANY(ARRAY{cols})
""")
src = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine)

# explore implementation in pgsql
# establish query string
cnames = []
for i, row in src.iterrows():
    s = text(f"""
        SELECT DISTINCT upper({row['column_name']}) AS cname FROM stage.{row['table_name']}
    """)
    cnames.append(str(s).strip())

sql = ' UNION '.join(cnames)

df = pd.read_sql(sql, con=engine)
```

The auto-generated SQL query string are then as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(cust_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyA UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(billing_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyA UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(cust_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyB UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(billing_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyB UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(cust_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyC UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(billing_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyC UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(cust_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyD UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT upper(billing_acc_name) AS cname FROM stage.journal_2017_companyD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plpgsql function may look like this:

```
create or replace function select_acc_names(_schema text)
returns setof text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select table_name, column_name
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_schema = _schema
        and column_name = any(array['cust_acc_name', 'billing_acc_name'])
    loop
        return query
        execute format ($fmt$
            select upper(%I) as cname
            from %I.%I
            $fmt$, rec.column_name, _schema, rec.table_name);
    end loop;
end $$;
```

Use:

```
select *
from select_acc_names('stage');
```